# Implementing AI to Air Hockey in SpriteKIt?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, artificial-intelligence

I am working on a game similar to air hockey in SpriteKit for fun and to learn Swift/Xcode. I anticipate the AI to be quite a challenge as there is other elements to the game which will need to be accounted for. I know I'll have to keep tackling each issue one by one. I have created the 2 player mode for the game, and I'm working on AI now. Here is some code I have used for calculating and delegating the impulse from mallet to puck (in the 2 player mode):

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    bottomTouchIsActive = true
    var releventTouch:UITouch!
    //convert set to known type
    let touchSet = touches

    //get array of touches so we can loop through them
    let orderedTouches = Array(touchSet)


    for touch in orderedTouches
    {
        //if we've not yet found a relevent touch
        if releventTouch == nil
        {
            //look for a touch that is in the activeArea (Avoid touches by opponent)
            if activeArea.contains(CGPoint(x: touch.location(in: parent!).x, y: touch.location(in: parent!).y + frame.height * 0.24))
            {
                isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                releventTouch = touch
            }
            else
            {
                releventTouch = nil
            }
        }
    }

    if (releventTouch != nil)
    {
        //get touch position and relocate player
        let location = CGPoint(x: releventTouch!.location(in: parent!).x, y: releventTouch!.location(in: parent!).y + frame.height * 0.24)
        position = location

        //find old location and use pythagoras to determine length between both points
        let oldLocation = CGPoint(x: releventTouch!.previousLocation(in: parent!).x, y: releventTouch!.previousLocation(in: parent!).y + frame.height * 0.24)
        let xOffset = location.x - oldLocation.x
        let yOffset = location.y - oldLocation.y
        let vectorLength = sqrt(xOffset * xOffset + yOffset * yOffset)

        //get eleapsed and use to calculate speed6A
        if  lastTouchTimeStamp != nil
        {
            let seconds = releventTouch.timestamp - lastTouchTimeStamp!
            let velocity = 0.01 * Double(vectorLength) / seconds

            //to calculate the vector, the velcity needs to be converted to a CGFloat
            let velocityCGFloat = CGFloat(velocity)

            //calculate the impulse
            let directionVector = CGVector(dx: velocityCGFloat * xOffset / vectorLength, dy: velocityCGFloat * yOffset / vectorLength)

            //pass the vector to the scene (so it can apply an impulse to the puck)
            delegate?.bottomForce(directionVector, fromBottomPlayer: self)
            delegate?.bottomTouchIsActive(bottomTouchIsActive, fromBottomPlayer: self)
        }
        //update latest touch time for next calculation
        lastTouchTimeStamp = releventTouch.timestamp
    }
}
```

I am wondering how I can convert this code for the AI. I have been adding some AI logic to the update function which I believe could also use time stamps and calculate distance traveled between frames to calculate the impulse. I just don't know exactly how to implement that thought. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Here is some bare bones code I have so far for testing purposes mostly for the AI mode in the update function:

```
    if (ball?.position.y)! < frame.height / 2
    {
        if (botPlayer?.position.y)! < frame.height * 0.75
        {
            botPlayer?.position.y += 1
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (botPlayer?.position.y)! > (ball?.position.y)!
        {
            if (botPlayer?.position.y)! - (ball?.position.y)! > frame.height * 0.1
            {
                botPlayer?.position.y -= 1
            }
            else
            {
                botPlayer?.position.y -= 3
            }
        }
        else
        {
            botPlayer?.position.y += 1
        }
    }
    if ((botPlayer?.position.x)! - (ball?.position.x)!) < 2
    {
        botPlayer?.position.x = (ball?.position.x)!
    }
    if (botPlayer?.position.x)! > (ball?.position.x)!
    {
        botPlayer?.position.x -= 2
    }
    else if (botPlayer?.position.x)! < (ball?.position.x)!
    {
        botPlayer?.position.x += 2
    }
```

Comment: Your question is too broad and will probably get close voted. That aside, try coding the AI paddle movement speed increasing the higher the difficulty. Slow speed = more misses. Faster reaction time = less misses by the AI.

Answer (score 0):

For AI to make a decision it must have information about the game state. To do this you can write a function that reads all available game data (placement of pucks, player scores, previous moves, etc) and returns the state as a dictionary. Then write a function to take in this dictionary, and output a decision. Consider this workflow in Python.

```
# we want the AI to make a decision

# start by grabbing game state
gameState = getGameState()

# pass this to the decision function
decision = getDecision( gameState )

# implement the decision
if decision == "move left":
    moveLeft()
else:
    moveRight()
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I like this idea but it is a bit more complex than I was planning on getting. I don't plan on implementing any machine learning/predictive AI. I am just trying to implement a bot which is capable of making logical decisions and has ability to defend/attack (simpler). How can I calculate this using time (update function) and change of distance for AI?

I want to convert the top block of code to be able to calculate a direction vector and force to apply as an impulse from the AI to the puck based on the AI's movement in the X and Y direction and delta time from update function.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to maintain a record of previous distance changes and the corresponding time stamps so the AI can use this information to make a decision? If so, you can use a global array of this data, and update it when needed. Then when you go to make your decision, check with the global array for the previous moves.